# How to send multipart messages using libnl and generic netlink?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, netlink

I'm trying to send a relatively big string (6Kb) through libnl and generic netlink, however, I'm receiving the error -5 (NL_ENOMEM) from the function `nla_put_string` in this process. I've made a lot of research but I didn't find any information about these two questions:

- What's the maximum string size supported by generic netlink and libnl `nla_put_string` function?
- How to use the multipart mechanism of generic netlink to broke this string in smaller parts to send and reassemble it on the Kernel side?

If there is a place to study such subject I appreciate that.

Comment: The default Netlink packet allocation functions reserve packets sized `PAGE_SIZE`. You then have to subtract Netlink and Generic Netlink headers from that. To get into more detail you'd have to state where you string is and where you want to send it. Userspace to Kernelspace? Kernelspace to Userspace? Kernelspace to Kernelspace? And if Userspace is involved, are you using libnl-genl-3?

Comment: My string is on userspace and I'm trying to send to Kernel. Yes, I'm using libnl-genl-3, I've tried to find some example which uses this mechanism but I didn't find any, did you know or have some example which a userspace application sends multipart messages to the Kernel using generic netlink?

Comment: As far as I know Netlink defers fragmentation to the application. (Which is good design IMO; humanity does not want another IPv4 fragmentation debacle.) But what's the problem with it? Just slice the string and send it in different packets.

Comment: Ping. Answer updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to use the multipart mechanism of generic netlink to broke this string in smaller parts to send and reassemble it on the Kernel side?

Netlink's Multipart feature "might" help you transmit an already fragmented string, but it won't help you with the actual string fragmentation operation. That's your job. Multipart is a means to transmit several small correlated objects through several packets, not one big object. In general, Netlink as a whole is designed with the assumption that any atomic piece of data you want to send will fit in a single packet. I would agree with the notion that 6Kbs worth of string is a bit of an oddball.

In actuality, Multipart is a rather ill-defined gimmic in my opinion. The problem is that the kernel doesn't actually handle it in any generic capacity; if you look at all the [`NLMSG_DONE` usage instances](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/A/ident/NLMSG_DONE), you will notice not only that it is very rarely read (most of them are writes), but also, it's not the Netlink code but rather some [specific protocol](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/samples/bpf/xdp_router_ipv4_user.c#L106) doing it for some `static` (ie. private) operation. In other words, the semantics of `NLMSG_DONE` are given by you, not by the kernel. Linux will not save you any work if you choose to use it.

On the other hand, libnl-genl-3 does appear to perform some automatic juggling with the Multipart flags (`NLMSG_DONE` and `NLM_F_MULTI`), but that only applies when you're sending something from Kernelspace to Userspace, and on top of that, even the library itself admits that [it doesn't really work](https://github.com/tgraf/libnl/blob/43bfe43fc58130efa3bda010621aef67a279faca/lib/nl.c#L879).

Also, `NLMSG_DONE` is supposed to be [placed in the "type" Netlink header field](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/samples/connector/ucon.c#L59), not in the "flags" field. This is baffling to me, because Generic Netlink [stores the family identifier in type](https://github.com/tgraf/libnl/blob/43bfe43fc58130efa3bda010621aef67a279faca/lib/genl/genl.c#L357), so it doesn't look like there's a way to simultaneously tell Netlink that the message belongs to you, AND that it's supposed to end some data stream. Unless I'm missing something important, Multipart and Generic Netlink are incompatible with each other.

I would therefore recommend implementing your own message control if necessary and forget about Multipart.

> What's the maximum string size supported by generic netlink and libnl nla_put_string function?

It's not a constant. [`nlmsg_alloc()`](https://github.com/tgraf/libnl/blob/43bfe43fc58130efa3bda010621aef67a279faca/lib/msg.c#L299) reserves
[`getpagesize()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getpagesize) bytes per packet [by default](https://github.com/tgraf/libnl/blob/43bfe43fc58130efa3bda010621aef67a279faca/lib/msg.c#L40). You can tweak this default with [`nlmsg_set_default_size()`](https://github.com/tgraf/libnl/blob/43bfe43fc58130efa3bda010621aef67a279faca/lib/msg.c#L365), or more to the point you can override it with [`nlmsg_alloc_size()`](https://github.com/tgraf/libnl/blob/43bfe43fc58130efa3bda010621aef67a279faca/lib/msg.c#L307).

Then you'd have to query the [actual allocated size](https://github.com/tgraf/libnl/blob/43bfe43fc58130efa3bda010621aef67a279faca/lib/msg.c#L594) (because it's not guaranteed to be what you requested) and build from there. To get the available payload you'd have to subtract the [Netlink header](https://github.com/tgraf/libnl/blob/43bfe43fc58130efa3bda010621aef67a279faca/include/linux-private/linux/netlink.h#L38) length, the [Generic Header](https://github.com/tgraf/libnl/blob/43bfe43fc58130efa3bda010621aef67a279faca/include/linux-private/linux/genetlink.h#L12) length and the [Attribute Header](https://github.com/tgraf/libnl/blob/43bfe43fc58130efa3bda010621aef67a279faca/include/linux-private/linux/netlink.h#L126) lengths for any attributes you want to add. Also the [user header length](https://github.com/tgraf/libnl/blob/43bfe43fc58130efa3bda010621aef67a279faca/lib/genl/genl.c#L320), if you have one. You would also have to align all these components because their `sizeof` is not necessarily their actual size ([example](https://github.com/tgraf/libnl/blob/43bfe43fc58130efa3bda010621aef67a279faca/include/linux-private/linux/netlink.h#L77)).

**All that said, the kernel will still reject packets which exceed the page size, so even if you specify a custom size you will still need to fragment your string.**

So really, just forget all of the above. Just fragment the string to something like `getpagesize() / 2` or whatever, and send it in separate chunks.

This is the general idea:

```
static void do_request(struct nl_sock *sk, int fam, char const *string)
{
    struct nl_msg *msg;

    msg = nlmsg_alloc();
    genlmsg_put(msg, NL_AUTO_PORT, NL_AUTO_SEQ, fam,
            0, 0, DOC_EXMPL_C_ECHO, 1);
    nla_put_string(msg, DOC_EXMPL_A_MSG, string);
    nl_send_auto(sk, msg);
    nlmsg_free(msg);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct nl_sock *sk;
    int fam;

    sk = nl_socket_alloc();
    genl_connect(sk);
    fam = genl_ctrl_resolve(sk, FAMILY_NAME);

    do_request(sk, fam, "I'm sending a string.");
    do_request(sk, fam, "Let's pretend I'm biiiiiig.");
    do_request(sk, fam, "Look at me, I'm so big.");
    do_request(sk, fam, "But I'm already fragmented, so it's ok.");
    
    nl_close(sk);
    nl_socket_free(sk);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I left a full sandbox in [my Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/no20h6tbu70td4a/SO62526613.tar.xz?dl=0). See the README. (Tested in kernel 5.4.0-37-generic.)